# autostart jwplayer html5 for iphone browser

Tags: html5-video, jwplayer

ive this code to run live streaming using jwplayer , its 2 part one if users was using PC and other if user using iphone , setting working fine for pc but when comes to html5  auto start never works , any tips to fix my configuration for html5

PS player working on iphone just when i click play ,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>live stream!</title>

    </head>
    <body>
         <br />
         <br />
         <br />
         <br />
         <br />
   <center>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/player/jwplayer.js'></script>
<div id='container'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

 jwplayer('container').setup({
 autostart: "true",
 file: "http://184.172.184.2:8000/;listen.pls",
 height: 300,
 width: 600,
 players: [
    { type: "flash", src: "player/player.swf", config: {provider: "sound"}  },
    {  type: "html5", config: {provider: "sound"}  }
  ],

  });

</script>
        <br />
         <br />
         <br />
Please click play  then wait 10 second for buffer ..... , Thanks
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

yo can't. but you could detect the ios browser and redirect it to the video itself, causing it to start..

javascript:

```
function isiPhone(){
    return (
        (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPhone") != -1) ||
        (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPod") != -1) ||
        (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPad") != -1)
    );
}
if(isiPhone()){
    window.location = "path/to/video.mp4";
}
```

or php:

```
<?php
    $userAgent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    if(
        strstr($userAgent,'iphone') ||
        strstr($userAgent,'ipod') ||
        strstr($userAgent,'ipad')
    )
    {
        header ("Location: path/to/video.mp4");
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, autostart does not work with iPhone's. This is what I gathered on some forums online.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gathered, autostart won't work on iOS devices as media playing needs to be activated via user interaction.  This leads to all kind of strange behaviour with playlists, for example -- I'm experiencing inconsistent firing of the "ended" event when playing mp3 files, tested with JWPlayer and pure HTML5 Audio objects.